# building a hashmap from an array in clojure

Tags: clojure, hashmap, zipmap

First off, I am a student in week 5 of 12 at The Iron Yard studying Java backend engineering. The course is composed of roughly 60% Java, 25% JavaScript and 15% Clojure.

I have been given the following problem (outlined in the comment):

```
;; Given an ArrayList of words, return a HashMap> containing a keys for every
;; word's first letter. The value for the key will be an ArrayList of all
;; words in the list that start with that letter. An empty string has no first
;; letter so don't add a key for it.
(defn index-words [word-list]
  (loop [word (first word-list)
         index {}]
    (if (contains? index (subs word 0 1))
      (assoc index (subs word 0 1) (let [words (index (subs word 0 1))
                                         word word]
                                     (conj words word)))
      (assoc index (subs word 0 1) (conj nil word)))
    (if (empty? word-list)
      index
      (recur (rest word-list) index))))
```

I was able to get a similar problem working using `zipmap` but I am positive that I am missing something with this one. The code compiles but fails to run.

Specifically, I am failing to update my hashmap index in the false clause of the 'if'.

I have tested all of the components of this function in the REPL, and they work in isolation. but I am struggling to put them all together.

For your reference, here is the code that calls word-list.

```
  (let [word-list ["aardvark" "apple" "zamboni" "phone"]]
    (printf "index-words(%s) -> %s\n" word-list (index-words word-list)))
```

Rather than getting a working solution from the community, my hope is for a few pointers to get my brain moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `assoc` does not modify `index`.  You need to work with the new value that `assoc` returns.  Same is true for `conj`: it does not modify the map you pass it.

I hope, this answer is of the nature you expected to get: just a pointer where your problem is.

BTW: If you can do with a `PersistentList` this becomes a one-liner when using `reduce` instead of `loop` and `recur`.  An interesting function for you could be `update-in`.

Have fun with Clojure.

Comment: that is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for. I will continue investigating and experimenting. I will update my this question with my final solution when I have it working.

Comment: So I have been playing around with this and have made some progress but I am stuck... '(reduce conj #{} word-list)' produces '=> #{"aardvark" "zamboni" "apple" "phone"}' but my goal is '#{ "a" ["aardvark"  "apple"], "z" ["zamboni"], "p" ["phone"]}'  or '#{ :a ["aardvark"  "apple"], :z ["zamboni"], :p ["phone"]}'

Comment: @cptully `#{:a :b :c}` is a set, that is, a collection of unique elements. You want a hash-map with keys to values `{:a 1, :b 2}`.

Comment: @cptully, consuider a more elaborate reduce function.  Remember that `reduce` takes a fn that takes two arguments: the accumulator (and finally result) and the current item.  You can write your own function for that.  The source of the standard function `frequencies` may be a good inspiration for you.

Answer (score 0):

The [`group-by`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/group-by) function does what you require.

- You can use `first` as its discriminating function argument. It
  returns the first character of a string, or `nil` if there isn't one:
  `(first word)` is simpler than `(subs word 0 1)`.
- Use `dissoc` to remove the entry for key `nil`.

---

You seldom need to use explicit `loop`s in clojure. Most common control patterns have been captured in functions like `group-by`. Such functions have function and possibly collection arguments. The commonest examples are `map` and `reduce`. The [Clojure cheat sheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html) is a most useful guide to them.